# Which scholars claimed Buddha was a messenger of God?

Tags: islamic-scholar, messengers

[Hamza Yusuf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamza_Yusuf) in *Buddha in the Qur'an* (viewed at [Scribd.com](https://www.scribd.com/doc/207936286/Buddha-in-the-Quran-by-Sh-Hamza-Yusuf-pdf)) writes:

> In classical Muslim literature on religions and sects, we find many references to "al-Badadah," meaning the Buddhists, as well as "al-Budd," the Buddha himself.  [Ibn al-Nadim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Al-Nadim) (d. 998), an Iraqi bookseller and author of the famous work entitled *The Compendium* (*al-Fihrist*), who catalogued existing authors and their subjects of study, records books that deal with Buddhism, including *The Life of Buddha* (*Kitab al-Budd*).  In his chapter entitled "Notes on the Buddha," Ibn al-Nadim delineates the different scholarly views of the Buddha: some believed he was the divine incarnate, **while others claimed he was a messenger of God**; still others thought Buddha to be a generic name for those who guided others onto the right path. ...

This makes me curious as to which Islamic scholars claimed that Buddha was a messenger of God.  The paper continues:

> Perhaps the most significant classical Muslim description of Buddhism is found in Imam Muhammad b. 'Abd al-Karim al-Shahrastani's (d. 1153) comprehensive survey entitled, *Religions and Sects* (*al-Milal wa al-nihal*).  ... In this work, he also makes a rather stunning--and intriguing--statement connecting the Buddha to a character in the Qur'an. ...
>
> > Based upon their description of the Buddha, if they are accurate, it would seem that he is none other than [al-Khadir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khidr), whom Muslims acknowledge, upon him be peace.

The phrasing suggests that al-Shahrastani did not hold this belief true, but rather acknowledged it as a possibility.  Therefore, I'm not sure who Hamza Yusuf is referring to.

**Question**: Which scholars claimed Buddha was a messenger of God?

Answer (score 2):

The founder of the Ahmadiyya sect (who is a false prophet by the consensus of Muslims) believed that Buddha was a prophet as well as Krishna. I came across this answer of his belief from a Buddhist - it's an interesting read: http://wenshuchan-online.weebly.com/a-buddhist-response-to-hadrat-mirza-ghulam-ahmad-of-qadian.html

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I am grateful of your informative question which made me making research and perceived the following information that:

> Teachings of early Buddhism
>
> a) Early Buddhism: Early Buddhism is very clear and in no need of any
>   philosophical understanding and analysis. Profound secrets and
>   philosophical complexities are something later Buddhists have added to
>   this religion. All Buddhism was about in the past was to awaken and
>   enlighten the people and free them from individual and social hardship
>   and give them inner and outer peace.
>   ...

Secondly, regarding “Which scholars claimed Buddha was a messenger of God?”, I remarked/found this issue/conclusion based on the book of **Jalaluddin Ashtiyani**.

Hopefully this answer helps you to some extent.

---

For further (and more accurate) information, kindly refer to the following source:

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa2512)

Comment: In that linked article it lists as a citation "Ibid, pg. 155". What or who is Ibid?

Comment: You are right, dear mate, but note that: ibid.
= in the same source (used to save space in textual references to a quoted work which has been mentioned in a previous reference).